# Getting 500 internal server error while executing POST request via AWS API Gateway & EBS for spring boot API

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, api, gateway

I have a springboot API & it has GET & POST function. I am getting 500 internal server error while executing POST request via AWS API Gateway & EBS for spring boot API. It returns complex object. The GET request works fine

```
          @GetMapping
          public String getServiceName(){          
            return "ok";
          }

    
           @PostMapping(
             value = "/saveData", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
             public ResponseObj saveData(@RequestBody MyRequest myrequestobj) 
              {
                 return service.saveData(myrequestobj);
              }
```

Comment: What do the logs say?

Comment: If you are getting 500 server error , how can you get complex object in return , please try to provide logs so that it can help to debug the issue

Comment: i dont have additional logs. i dont know how to get logs from aws. the only thing i see is 500 internal server error. In swagger, i donr get any error. it executes successfully